# Distinguish a string literal from a string C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-literals

I want to do something like

```
IsItAStringLiteral("yes")
var v = "no";
IsItAStringLiteral(v)
```

With the obvious return value. Is it possible?

Comment: Is this purely academic, or is there some use for it?

Comment: Seriosly, wtf do you need, please elaborate.

Comment: because i liked the way Vinay Pandey asked. To make string.format(literal_only, anythingelse) be more safe. However i am not outputting strings but html or sql or etc

Comment: @acidzombie24, in this case I think make it "safe" is going to also make it less powerful.

Comment: @tster: For html, i never needed to build the format arg. For SQL i have but i remember thinking it isnt pretty and it has caused trouble. I dont think this will be any less useful in HTML case and will have me use the unsafe string way in the odd and usual problem causing SQL statement unless i write something up to handle that which i might not bc i have only needed it once.

Comment: Safe way; sanitize your input.  Who cares where it comes from?  Just clean it up.

Comment: I'm reminded why i dont like explaining things. Half the ppl here seemed to miss the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the string.IsInterned method to determine whether a given string is in the .NET intern pool. All string literals are automatically added to the intern pool before the application begins running.

Of course, that won't help you with your exact question. Variable 'v' will reference a string literal, so it too will appear in the intern pool. Why do you need such functionality?

Comment: @acidzombie, can you please explain what did you use it for, can be useful to others

Comment: @Vinay Pandey: ok sure i added the comment to my question.

Comment: _"so it too will appear in the intern pool"_ -- in addition, code can add strings to the intern pool at runtime. The bottom line is that it is _not_ possible to know whether the passed value is a string literal or not.

Answer (score 4):

No.  You won't be able to tell whether a string is a literal or not.

The simple reason: Literals, string variables, interned strings of all kinds....each one is a reference to a System.String.  And all strings, when passed by value, are loaded onto the stack prior to the function call that uses them (and thus, are unrelated to the name of any variable that references them).  By the time the function is called, a literal and a variable look exactly the same, and will be treated exactly the same when passed by value.

The only way that might be possible is some `unsafe` stuff that might check the address of the object.  If the address is within an assembly's address space, it almost certainly came from a constant of some sort.  But that's unreliable (as strings set to literals would look just like the literals), extremely hackish, ugly, and above all unnecessary for any purpose that i can think of.

You should probably reconsider how you're doing whatever you're doing, if you have to care whether a string is a literal or not.