# Is there a way to limit actual parameter values in C# to only string literals

Tags: c#

What I mean is something like

```
public class C1 {
   public string ProcessString([StringLiteralsOnly] string s) { ... }
   readonly string S1 = ProcessString("this is a string literal"); // good
   readonly string V2 = "This is a variable";
   readonly string S2 = ProcessString(V2); // should be ERROR or warning due to [StringLiteralsOnly]
}
```

If no zero-force way, any idea of how this workflow might be implemented?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spec_Sharp

Comment: You could implement a custom code analysis rule that would detect this but I ask the same as @sr28, why do you need this?

Comment: First of all, to easily locate the content of some kind of strings.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karsen, can you share a link to thedescription of the way of the custom code analysis rule?

Comment: It would have to be source analysis. Code analysis would be roughly possible (look for ldstr) but it would give false negatives if the string was then put into a local and taken out again in the produced code, and false positives if `string.Empty` was replaced by `""` as the compiler often does. At runtime you could verify `ReferenceEquals(s, string.IsInterned(s))` but that could be false either way. It wouldn't ban `const string` but whether that's desirable or not is hard to say.

Comment: Hmm. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947764/distinguish-a-string-literal-from-a-string-c-sharp ? Sometimes I dislike the auto-close gold-badge power, I'd rather vote to close as duplicate and see if enough people agree with me.

Comment: @JonHanna: thanks for not closing that, as I don't think it's really a duplicate. The question you refer to is asking how the called method can distinguish the two, while this question appears to be asking for a compile-time message of some sort.

Comment: Please explain what it is you're actually trying to accomplish. I.e. what "workflow" _is_ it that you are trying to accomplish? What is the end goal here? There is no way to do literally what you are asking for, but it's clear you've got some broader goal in mind, but [have asked about some specific solution instead of that goal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: >>> @Peter Please explain what it is you're actually trying to accomplish. I.e. what "workflow" is it that you are trying to accomplish?

<=======>


First of all, to force the developers hardcode the stings they use, so as to then easily locate the content of this kind of strings. By grep or ReSharper. And this is exactly I currently want to know or find out.

Comment: _"to force the developers hardcode the stings they use, so as to then easily locate the content of this kind of strings"_ -- lacking more context, I can only point out that the usual and best way to ensure ease of identification of string literals and other constants is to use actual constants (i.e. `const` fields). Then normal code navigation tools can immediately and quickly find all uses. As for _forcing_ developers to do this, there are no language features I know of that would do that; but you can probably implement a code analyzer in Roslyn for that purpose.